# Mybatis generator mapper and example catn't inject to service layer(resolution)

Tags: spring, jsf, mybatis, mybatis-generator

- My project is use jsf-spring-mybatis framework,I use mybatis-generator create dao,mapper and model,also include model example, project on github address is [jsf-spring-mybatis project](https://github.com/ragrok/spring_jsf_mybatis).
- controller layer

  ```
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{employeeService}")
  private EmployeeFace face;
  public void login() {
      if (face.validateLoginInfo(this.getName(), this.getPassword())) {
          Util.redirect(Constants.STATIC_URL + "index.xhtml");
      } else {
          Util.redirect(Constants.ERROR_URL + "error.xhtml");
      }
  }

  public String getName() {
      return Name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      Name = name;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
      return Password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
      Password = password;
  }
  ```

  - service layer

    ```
    @Autowired
    EmployeeExample example;
    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper mapper;

        public boolean validateLoginInfo(String name, String password) {
            boolean flag = false;
            Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
            criteria.andEmployeePasswordEqualTo(password);
            criteria.andEmployeeIdEqualTo(name);
            List<Employee> employees = mapper.selectByExample(example);
            if (!employees.isEmpty()) {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

    }
    ```
- Example.java in model layer

`public Criteria createCriteria() {
            Criteria criteria = createCriteriaInternal();
            if (oredCriteria.size() == 0) {
                oredCriteria.add(criteria);
            }
            return criteria;
        }`

- ExampleMapper.xml

```
   <select id="selectByExample" parameterType="cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Mon Sep 19 10:59:27 CST 2016.
    -->
    select
    <if test="distinct">
      distinct
    </if>
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from employee
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
    <if test="orderByClause != null">
      order by ${orderByClause}
    </if>
  </select>
    <sql id="Example_Where_Clause">
        <!--
          WARNING - @mbggenerated
          This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
          This element was generated on Mon Sep 19 10:59:27 CST 2016.
        -->
        <where>
          <foreach collection="oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or">
            <if test="criteria.valid">
              <trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides="and" suffix=")">
                <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion">
                  <choose>
                    <when test="criterion.noValue">
                      and ${criterion.condition}
                    </when>
                    <when test="criterion.singleValue">
                      and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                    </when>
                    <when test="criterion.betweenValue">
                      and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
                    </when>
                    <when test="criterion.listValue">
                      and ${criterion.condition}
                      <foreach close=")" collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" separator=",">
                        #{listItem}
                      </foreach>
                    </when>
                  </choose>
                </foreach>
              </trim>
            </if>
          </foreach>
        </where>
      </sql>
```

- Eclipse console information

```
2016-09-20 09:22:45,574 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample cn.com.github.service.impl.EmployeeImpl.example; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample cn.com.github.service.impl.EmployeeImpl.example; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
九月 20, 2016 9:22:45 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
严重: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample cn.com.github.service.impl.EmployeeImpl.example; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample cn.com.github.service.impl.EmployeeImpl.example; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.github.model.EmployeeExample] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
```

- update service layer

  ```
  public boolean validateLoginInfo(String name, String password) {
      boolean flag = false;
      EmployeeExample example = new EmployeeExample();
      Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
      criteria.andEmployeePasswordEqualTo(password);
      criteria.andEmployeeIdEqualTo(name);
      List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)mapper.selectByExample(example);
      if (!employees.isEmpty()) {
          flag = true;
      }
      return flag;
  }
  ```
- Add getter and setter function with service interface in controller layer

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{employeeService}")
      private EmployeeFace face;

  ```
  public void login() {
      if (face.validateLoginInfo(this.getName(), this.getPassword())) {
          Util.redirect(Constants.STATIC_URL + "index.xhtml");
      } else {
          Util.redirect(Constants.ERROR_URL + "error.xhtml");
      }
  }

  public String getName() {
      return Name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      Name = name;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
      return Password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
      Password = password;
  }

  public EmployeeFace getFace() {
      return face;
  }

  public void setFace(EmployeeFace face) {
      this.face = face;
  }
  ```
- Add model a null construct
- OK, solve this problem.

Comment: You have a Spring configuration problem rather than a MyBatis problem. You tried to inject `EmployeeExample` on your service but on your applicationContext configuration you are scanning only the service package `<context:component-scan base-package="cn.com.github.service" />` I found more little erros on your project also. To much to make an answer, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I konw, can you take me some advice to Spring configuration?